# Java KeyListener keyPressed method fires too fast

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

If you use the java `KeyListener` class you know that if you hold down a key `keyPressed` will fire one `KeyEvent`, and then about half a second later will fire the same key many times very very fast.  I would like to know if there is a way to keep the `KeyEvents` from firing too fast.  I would like them to be at a nice constant rate of about once every 500 ms.

Answer (score 7):

You can, but the trick is to not slow down the firing of events, but to slow down how fast you process them:

```
KeyListener kl = new KeyListener() {
    private long lastPressProcessed = 0;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPressProcessed > 500) {
            //Do your work here...
            lastPressProcessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   }

};
```

Comment: This will only work well if the system key-repeat is very rapid. If it is, say, 400 ms between presses, then this may cause delays on up to 900 ms.

Comment: @aioobe - There's no way around that, I think, other than changing the system autorepeat rate. It's a property of undersampling; there's going to be aliasing, which will appear as a jittery repeat time. If you are processing long streams of autorepeat events, then one can apply antialiasing techniques to reduce the jitter, but I doubt that long streams of autorepeat events are a common application.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is completely system dependent. You would have to listen for `keyPressed` events, start a timer on your own that fires events at a fixed rate and stop it at the next `keyReleased` event.

Try something like this:

```
component.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        tt.cancel();
        tt = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (tt != null)
            return;

        tt = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000);
            }
        };

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by your OS.  But you could easily have your handler check how long it is since the last time it fired and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the auto-repeat rate for keys is set by the system; I don't know if it's changeable from within Java. However, you can use the event arrival time to not react to one until 500ms after the last time you reacted (or after a key release, which should clear the timer for users who type fast).