# Java Game Programming Part 1: Smooth Movement

Tags: java, swing, pacman

I'm one third of a three member group in a computer class (high school freshmen). For our project we decided to make a Pac-Man style game in Java. None of us have much experience, so we've essentially been teaching ourselves up to this point. We've made quite a bit of progress, but we seem to have reached a standstill at this point. Here are our main questions:

1. How can we make our Pacman (Fatman) move smoothly across the tiles? He moves tile by tile, but that looks unprofessional. In addition, when you hold down the arrow keys he zips across the screen. How can we prevent that from happening?

(I have other things I need help on but they are in different questions)

Thank you for your help!

Here is our code so far:

**Maze Class:**

```
package Fatman;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Maze {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Maze();
    }

    public Maze(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Fatman!");
        f.add(new Board());
        f.setSize(816, 838);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Map Class**

```
    package Fatman;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Map {

    private Scanner m;
    private String Map[] = new String[25]; 

    private Image spaceregcandy,
                  srcb,
                  safehouse,
                  spacebigcandy,
                  blackspace,
                  space,
                  portal1,
                  portal2,
                  wall;

    public Map(){

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\spaceregcandy.png");
        spaceregcandy = img.getImage();
        //image icon has already been initiated, so it doesn't have to be written again
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\spaceregcandyblue.png");
        srcb = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\safehouse.png");
        safehouse = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\wall232x.png");
        wall = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\spacebigcandy.png");
        spacebigcandy = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\blackspace.png");
        blackspace = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\space.png");
        space = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\portal1.png");
        portal1 = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\portal2.png");
        portal2 = img.getImage();

        openFile();
        readFile();
        closeFile();
        }

    public Image getSpaceregcandy(){
        return spaceregcandy;
    }
    public Image getSrcb(){
        return srcb;
    }
    public Image getSafehouse(){
        return safehouse;
    }
    public Image getWall(){
        return wall;
    }
    public Image getSpacebigcandy(){
        return spacebigcandy;
    }
    public Image getBlackspace(){
        return blackspace;
    }
    public Image getSpace(){
        return space;
    }
    public Image getPortal1(){
        return portal1;
    }
    public Image getPortal2(){
        return portal2;
    }

    public String getMap(int x, int y){
        String index = Map[y].substring(x, x + 1);
        return index;
        //in y position, if y = 2, goes to second row (substring gets x position)
    }

    public void openFile(){

        try{
        m = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\map3.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error loading map");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        while(m.hasNext()){
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
                Map[i] = m.next();
            }
        }

    }

    public void closeFile(){
        m.close();
    }
}
```

**Board Class**

```
package Fatman;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Timer timer;

    private Image player;

    private Map m;
    private Player p;

    public Board(){

        m = new Map();
        p = new Player();
        addKeyListener(new Al());
        setFocusable(true);
        timer = new Timer(1, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        repaint();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);

        for(int y = 0; y < 25; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x <25; x++){
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("o")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSpaceregcandy(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("O")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSrcb(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("x")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getWall(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("H")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSafehouse(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }   
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("C")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSpacebigcandy(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("b")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getBlackspace(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("s")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getSpace(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("p")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getPortal1(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
                if(m.getMap(x, y).equals("P")){
                    g.drawImage(m.getPortal2(), x *32, y *32, null);
                }
        }


    }


        g.drawImage(p.getPlayer(), p.getTileX() * 32, p.getTileY() * 32, null);

}

    public class Al extends KeyAdapter{

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() -1).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() -1).equals("b")){                       
                        }
                        p.move(0, -1);                  

                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));

            }
                }

            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() +1).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY() +1).equals("b")){
                        p.move(0, 1);
                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));
            }
                }
            }
            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() - 1, p.getTileY()).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() - 1, p.getTileY()).equals("b")){
                        p.move(-1, 0);
                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));
            }
                }
            }
            if(keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() + 1, p.getTileY()).equals("x")){
                    if(!m.getMap(p.getTileX() + 1, p.getTileY()).equals("b")){
                        p.move(1, 0);
                        System.out.println(m.getMap(p.getTileX(), p.getTileY()));
            }
            }
            }
            }


        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}
}
}
```

**Player Class**

```
package Fatman;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player {

    private int tileX, tileY;
    private int dx, dy;

    private Image player; 

    public Player(){

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Martin\\Desktop\\Fatman Project\\FATMANsimplified32xbrown.png");
        player = img.getImage();

        tileX = 12;
        tileY = 18;
    }

    public Image getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }
    public int getTileX(){
        return tileX;
    }
    public int getTileY(){
        return tileY;
    }

    public void move(int dx, int dy){

        tileX += dx;
        tileY += dy;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use [Threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial).

Comment: This is kind of a broad question.  You should try to break it down into more-specific questions.

Comment: Don't move your pacman in the keylistener. Set a flag so that you know the key is down, and move accordingly in a thread, whilst checking these flags. There's also something called KeyBinding that I see people talk about a lot, but I don't know much about them. It's supposed to be better though

Answer (score 1):

Well for your first question, recognize that you're just incrementing the tile numbers in your move method, and later on repainting the player at that location (with an increment of 32 pixels). You need finer level of granularity than that, that is incrementing not by tiles themselves, but by portion of tiles (e.g. by 2 pixels). So that FatMan's image would take more steps to move from 1 tile to another. Obviously it would look even better if FatMan's image player a walking/running animation during that time, to make movement seem more natural.

So... in shameless self promotion I invite you to take a look at my old tutorial here:
https://sites.google.com/site/javagamescorner/home/animated-sprites

Comment: I know you probably have better things to do than help out a fifteen year old kid, but considering the fact that my knowledge of Java is very rudimentary, would you mind explaining a little further? How would I make it so that our character moves pixel by pixel, rather than tile by tile? The only thing I can think of is coming up with a variable that represents the center of the image and adding x to that every y milliseconds as long as another button hasn't been pressed... I'm not sure how that would work, though (if at all). Thank you so much for your help! It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

First of all you need some sort of sleep/pause between each update to simulate time, otherwise the player will instantly jump to the end of the map if you keep the key pressed. Since you want to have some time passed after each step the player takes.

One possibility is to add Thread.sleep after each call.

Second you need decouple the player movement from your tile coordinate system. If you want that the player is able to "move between the tiles". He should use his own coordinate system allowing him to move smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your fatman to slip right to left and vice-versa, you can refer to this question : [Java KeyListener keyPressed method fires too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199581/java-keylistener-keypressed-method-fires-too-fast)

For your animation, you'll have to code something to move 1 tile to another yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your code and I propose you these modifications:

- When you press a key you set a direction which can be up, down, left or right as next direction (because direction must be keep until the move is finished). You can implemented with two class variables: direction and nextDirection. You also set another class variable with the value of the edge size of your tile (for example, 32). This variable is called animationFrame.
- In this example you set the timer frecuency more or less to 32 Hz (1000/32 milliseconds). You can play with the timer to fit the animation.
- Each time the timer is called, you move 1 pixel the image of your fatman in the direction (read direction variable) and you decrease animationFrame. When you reach 0 then fatman is placed in the next tile. You can reapeat the operation by setting direction = nextDirection. And now you have to apply the logic of the game at this point (collisions, etc.).

This is only a rough approach but I think you can start from this idea. This kindly reminds me the snake game I programmed in java when I was 16 years old.